# Grouping Consecutive Timestamps (Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Got something that I cant get my head around

raw data shows every 15 min intervals and I would like to group them based on if they are consecutive 15 min intervals (see screenshot below) I will like to do this multiple times for each user and for alot of users... Any ideas on how to do this using sql only that can scale to 1000's users?

[image]

Any help would be appreicated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  Use `lag()` to get the difference, then a cumulative sum to identify the group:

```
select user_id, min(start_time), max(end_time)
from (select t.*,
             sum( case when prev_end_time <> start_time then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by user_id order by start_time) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(end_time) over (partition by user_id order by start_time) as prev_end_time
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by user_id, grp;
```

Comment: I was trying to go this way but couldnt get there. Thanks this helped